# MS Access Skip function

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am creating a database on MS Access currently and was wondering if there was a way to program it to automatically skip over certain fields based on an answer in a previous fields?

Comment: please add more detail to your question.  An example scenario is usually helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.  For example, if you put the following code in the `AfterUpdate` event of the `txtLastName` textbox:

```
If txtLastName = ""
    me.txtFieldToBeSkippedTo.SetFocus
End If
```

Comment: This is a different approach than I had thought, but it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

By skip, do you mean to *hide* the field or just *tab over it*?  Either way, you'll probably need to write some custom VBA code to help you solve the problem.

To get you started, look at adding some VBA code to the *AfterUpdate* event of the field that will determine whether another field is shown.  Within the procedure for that event, write code to either hide (`.Visible`) or remove from the tab order (I think it's `.TabStop`) the controls that you want skipped.

Comment: AfterUpdate seems to me to be the only correct event, as OnChange fires with every keystroke.

Comment: @David that's a good point. I had forgotten how the *OnChange* event fired.

Answer (score 0):

You could equally make it impossible for them to enter data in it by disabling it:

```
Me.f2.Enabled = False
Me.f2.Locked = True
```

The lock prevents you from changing data in it. Turning off enable prevents you from entering the field at all. If you both, it will to keep it from greying out the field - which may or may not be what you want.